# Derive a polygon from the midpoints of the sides of a given polygon

Tags: geometry, homework

> Write a function that creates a new figure (a new broken line) out of a given broken line. It would take as parameter a list of (max) 20 points representing the closed broken line. The output must be a plot with the two figures in different colors.
>
> The new figure is created by connecting midpoints of consecutive segments of the figure.
>
> Suggestion. Keep the coordinates of the randomly generated points in a symmetrical interval, for simplicity.
>
> Observation. A closed broken line is a figure made of segments such that each segment's left endpoint is connected to another segment's right endpoint.

Given four points, the output should be similar to this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a homework problem and we generally like to see what you've tried before we try to help.

Comment: `ListLinePlot` might be of interest.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark before the edit it was

Comment: This is not a do-my-homework site.

Answer (score 3):

I would typically not answer this kind of questions, but this was interesting to me:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[5348]; pts = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {4, 2}]];

Graphics[{
    FaceForm[None],
    EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], Polygon[pts],
    EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], Polygon[Mean /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, {1, 1}]]
  },
  Axes -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Usually, I use `ListCorrelate[]` instead of `Mean[]` + `Partition[]`, but this works.